# Reduce brightness of a product image with a background

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagick

I have an image where I need to change the color-profile from RGB to sRGB. Simultaneously, with the transforming the image. The image has a background. Brightness of the image should be reduced without changing background brightness.
this is what I am trying right now.

```
convert 1.jpeg -colorspace RGB +sigmoidal-contrast 11.6933 -define filter:filter=Sinc -define filter:window=Jinc -define filter:lobes=3 -resize 400% -sigmoidal-contrast 11.6933 -colorspace sRGB 1_srgb.jpg
```

How to decrease the brightness of the product image?

I need a solution to run on a bunch of such images through the command line. i would prefer some PHP based solution.

Comment: Is the example you provided working as expected and the only thing is to make it working with multiple images?

Comment: No this is converting the image to sRGB and I can use it on multiple images. I am looking to reduce the brightness of the image without affecting its background.

Comment: You need to have an image with separate layers for that, one layer as a background and one as a foreground to achieve good quality and repeatability. Do you have such multilayer images or you have them only as jpeg?

Comment: I have them only as JPEG.

Comment: Then you need something called masking to selectively apply changes only to the foreground (your image) and not to the background. Automated masking is only feasible if you have your background in distinct color in comparison to the background. In other words your image cannot have anywhere the same color as the background has. Automated background masking is a part of [image keying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key). If your product image may have similar colors to the bacground image then I'm afraid the process cannot be automated and mask must be created manually by drawing

Comment: Can you provide a few samples which are representative of your entire dataset? As @jimmix mentioned, you need a foreground mask for each image, so you will be able to apply your functions separately.

Comment: Here is the sample https://ibb.co/TbVk6JZ

Comment: We want to improve the image for iPhone and mac. The image looks good for android devices. But on iPhones the colours are not satisfactory. There is dullness on dell monitors too, which are optimised for ant-glare.